# Find $h(85)$ if $h(x^2+x+3)+2h(x^2-3x+5)=6x^2-10x+17$

Tags: functional-equations

let : $h: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ ane for any real number

$$h(x^2+x+3)+2h(x^2-3x+5)=6x^2-10x+17$$

then :

$$h(85)=?$$

My Try: $$x=0:h(3)+2h(5)=17\\x=1:h(5)+2h(3)=13\\+\\3h(3)+3h(5)=30\\h(3)+h(5)=10$$

now ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $h(x) \equiv Ax+B$, then $$A(x^2+x+3)+B+2A(x^2-3x+5)+2B\equiv 6x^2-10x+17$$

$$
\left \{
\begin{align*}
  3A &= 6 \\
  -5A &= -10 \\
  13A+2B &= 17 \\
\end{align*}
\right.$$

On solving, $(A,B)=\left( 2, -\dfrac{9}{2} \right)$

---

Alternatively,

- $x=\dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{329}}{2} \implies x^2+x+3=85 \quad \text{and} \quad x^2-3x+5=89 \mp \sqrt{329}$
- $x=\dfrac{3 \pm \sqrt{329}}{2} \implies x^2-3x+5=85 \quad \text{and} \quad x^2+x+3=89 \pm \sqrt{329}$
- If you substitute $x=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{329}}{2}$ and $x=\dfrac{3-\sqrt{329}}{2}$, you can solve $h(85)$ and $h(89-\sqrt{329})$.
- If you substitute $x=\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{329}}{2}$ and $x=\dfrac{3+\sqrt{329}}{2}$, you can solve $h(85)$ and $h(89+\sqrt{329})$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote: $x^2+x+3=t$. Then:
$$h(t)+2h(t-4x+2)=6t-16x-1.$$
Plug $x=\frac{1}{2}$ to get:
$$h(t)+2h(t)=6t-9 \Rightarrow h(t)=2t-3.$$
Hence:
$$h(85)=2\cdot 85-3=167.$$

Comment: Nice thought, but sadly your solution fails when you plug $x=\frac{1}{2}$ in there, since then you will have that $t=\frac{15}{4}$.

Comment: @HeatTheIce, nice objection, yes the variables $x$ and $t$ are interdependent. If they are considered independent from line 2 onward, the argument works. Can you give a counterexample for this method that gives wrong answer?

Comment: Everything is fine up until "hence", beacause $t$, or better said $t(x)$ has a fixed value for a fixed value of x. So you only have proven that $h(\frac{15}{4})=\frac{9}{2}$. For you to say that $h(t)=2t-3$ would only be an assumption and not a proof. For it to be proven you need to check it and then verify there are no other solution exists.
Sadly I can't give you an example where it wouldn't work, but I think you get the idea why it can't be right. It can be used as a hint for you where the solution is leading you, but a solution on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

For a general way of solving this, look at my answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2819063/fx2-x2fx2-3x-2-9x2-15x-then-find-f2016/2819289#2819289).

When supposing it's a linear function, you also have to prove it can't be anything else, so your solution is complete.